# SearchView: can't capture the close event

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I use the ActionBarShellock 4.2. I think the OnCloseListener() would be called when I click the closebutton but no response when i did it.

```
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "OnCloseListener", 1000).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've tried to call the getChildAt(index) to get the closebutton. Then I think it's unsafe cause the SearchView is not my own code. So, how can I capture the close event? Did I do in the wrong way? 
thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You've asked two completely unrelated questions in one. One per thread, please. (You can post a second thread for one of the questions.) And you should probably provide more detail, as you haven't really explained much about (either of) your problems.

Comment: @Eric sorry. i'll put it right

Comment: @Eric done. did i explain clearly? tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get your menuItem, then setOnActionExpandListener. Then override unimplents methods.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

   //do something on close
   // you must return true
    return true;
}
```

Hack done
good luck

Comment: The problem that blackdog was having was effecting me on [Android v4.1 (API 16) and v4.2 (API 17)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels). This is a non-ActionBarSherlock project, so it's _probably_ safe to say that this oddity occurs on all versions of Android around today. But anyway, your fix definitely worked for me, thanks a ton!